# Having trouble with JS/jQ on the 'use strict' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small function that I'm using to change the background of an HTML file, but JSLint keeps returning the"'Missing 'use strict' staetment" error message even after I've tried many, many things.

Any help as to how I could fix this issue?

Here's the JS -

```
/*jslist browser = true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
/*jshint strict: true*/


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#black').click(function () {
        'use strict';
        $('.outer-container').css('background-color', '#000');
        $('.outer-container').css('color', '#fff');
        $('a:link').css('color', 'white');
        $('a.hover').css('color', 'white');
        $('a:visited').css('color', 'white');
    });
});
```

Comment: `use strict` needs to be the very first line of the function according to the MDN convention

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Is it not in this example? It's the first line of the `click` handler function.

Comment: @Cory I don't understand it either, but it still returns the error

Comment: Maybe it needs to be abstracted from the click function

Comment: @SterlingArcher how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Put it under the document ready function perhaps? I'm not 100% sure how use strict works with jQuery

Comment: @SterlingArcher putting it under the first function worked.  Thanks, I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Sure! I'll throw it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

The `use strict` case is bound to the click function, whereas it should be under the document ready function.